# Izpack 5.0 & Maven - Build successful, but shortcut not appearing on Desktop

Tags: windows, maven, installation, shortcut, izpack

I've been working on an installer using Izpack 5.0 and Maven. The is created and working, and I can create a shortcut for an uninstaller within the program directory, but I cannot get a shortcut on the desktop.

Here is my shortcutSpec.xml (with actual application name replaced with Program Name for privacy):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>

<izpack:shortcuts version="5.0"
              xmlns:izpack="http://izpack.org/schema/shortcuts"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://izpack.org/schema/shortcuts        
              http://izpack.org/schema/5.0/izpack-shortcuts-5.0.xsd">

<programGroup defaultName="Program Name" location="applications"/>

<shortcut
        name="Uninstaller"
        programGroup="yes"
        desktop="yes"
        applications="no"
        startMenu="no"
        startup="no"
        target="$INSTALL_PATH\Uninstaller\uninstaller.jar"
        commandLine=""
        iconFile="%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll"
        iconIndex="31"
        description="This uninstalls the test">

    <createForPack name="Core"/>
</shortcut>

</izpack:shortcuts>
```

And here is my install.xml:

```
<izpack:installation version="5.0"
                 xmlns:izpack="http://izpack.org/schema/installation"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://izpack.org/schema/installation      
                 http://izpack.org/schema/5.0/izpack-installation-5.0.xsd">

 <info>
     <appname>Program Name </appname>
     <appversion>1.0</appversion>
     <javaversion>1.8</javaversion>
 </info>

<locale>
    <langpack iso3="eng"/>
</locale>

<natives>
    <native type="izpack" name="ShellLink.dll"/>
    <native type="izpack" name="ShellLink_x64.dll"/>
</natives>

<res src="shortcutSpec.xml" id="shortcutSpec.xml"/>

<guiprefs height="400" resizable="no" width="640">
    <modifier key="useButtonIcons" value="yes"/>
    <modifier key="useLabelIcons" value="no"/>
    <modifier key="labelGap" value="2"/>
    <modifier key="layoutAnchor" value="NORTHWEST"/>
    <modifier key="useHeadingPanel" value="no"/>
    <modifier key="headingImageOnLeft" value="yes"/>
    <modifier key="headingLineCount" value="1"/>
    <modifier key="headingFontSize" value="1.5"/>
    <modifier key="headingBackgroundColor" value="0x00ffffff"/>
    <modifier key="headingPanelCounter" value="progressbar"/>
    <modifier key="headingPanelCounterPos" value="inNavigationPanel"/>
</guiprefs>

<panels>
    <panel classname="TargetPanel"/>
    <panel classname="PacksPanel"/>
    <panel classname="InstallPanel"/>
    <panel classname="FinishPanel"/>
 </panels>

 <packs>
    <pack name="Core" required="yes">
        <description>Core installation files</description>
        <file src="..\ProgramName.jar" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH" unpack="false" />
    </pack>
 </packs>

</izpack:installation>
```

**Any help is greatly appreciated!**

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove **izpack:shortcuts** element from shortcutSpec xml. Here is what I have in my shortcutSpec xml and it works great. I have tried wrapping **shortcuts** element inside **izpack:shortcuts** and it never worked.
2. Wrap **shortcut** inside **shortcuts**

   ```html
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
       <shortcuts>
        <shortcut 
                   name="Falcon"
                   target="$INSTALL_PATH/falcon.exe"
                   description="Falcon"
                   programGroup="false"
                   desktop="true"
                   startMenu="true"
                   runAsAdministrator="true"
               />
       </shortcuts>
   ```

Comment: -1 dont just randomly post your code just because it's working for you. He is using izpack 5.0 https://izpack.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/IZPACK/pages/491733/Shortcut+Specification

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following native libraries to your install.xml:

```
  <natives>
    <native type="izpack" name="ShellLink.dll" />
    <native type="izpack" name="ShellLink_x64.dll" />
  </natives>
```

These are responsible for creating the shortcuts during installation.

This is also explained in detail in the [IzPack Shortcut Panel Documentation](https://izpack.atlassian.net/wiki/display/IZPACK/Shortcut+Panel) .

Comment: Sorry must have overlooked that.